# How to specify a function that takes a void* in C++ OCX module?

Tags: c++, vb6, activex, arrays, ocx

I have written a OCX module in VC++2010, to be used with a legacy VB6 app. In it, I have one function which is supposed to take an array of arbitrary data (a pointer into memory).

The function is implemented as an empty body right now and declared as:

```
afx_msg void Test(void const* pSrc);
```

The dispatch map is:

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(COcxTestCtrl, COleControl)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(COcxTestCtrl, "Test", 1, Test, VT_EMPTY, VTS_PI1 /*??*/)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
```

and the IDL file says:

```
dispinterface _DOcxTest {
    properties:
    methods:     [id(1)] void Test(void const* pSrc);
};
```

VB6's object catalog lists the type of the function as

```
Sub Test(pSrc As Any)
Member of OcxTestLib.OcxTest
```

and my calling code is

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click()
    Dim text() As Byte
    Dim buflen As Long
    buflen = 2 ^ 16
    text = String(buflen, "Z")
    OcxTest1.Test (text(0))
End Sub
```

However, it always tells me "Error 13: Types incompatible". This is the only type I'm having problems with, all other calls are made as planned.

I have played around with using `char const*`, `byte const*`, `INT8 const*` instead of `void const*` but none of this works. When I use `INT8 const*`, VB6 lists the function as `Sub Test(pSrc As Byte)` but I still get the same error.

How can I pass a pointer to the Byte array to the OCX module?

Comment: void* is not an Automation compatible type.  Use VARIANT instead.  Or SAFEARRAY if you want to pass an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Byte array in VB is already a native SAFEARRAY, so pass it to the OCX as a SAFEARRAY (or a VARIANT containing a SAFEARRAY).

Comment: Passing as `VARIANT` containing `SAFEARRAY` worked: `static_cast<unsigned char const*>((*(pSrc->pparray))->pvData)` :)